# Alchemy - List of craftable potions with multiple effects

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a complete list of the ingredients that can be used to craft potions with multiple effects?

I have seen complete lists for [ingredients](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ingredients) and [effects](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy_Effects) but I would like a smaller list of only ingredient combinations that result in multi-effect potions/poisons.

If such a list does not yet exist, I could create it based on the other lists. But first I would need some clarification on what happens if two ingredients share more than two effects, or if they have both a positive and a negative effect.

For example, both `Dwarven Oil` and `Taproot` have the exact same effects: Weakness to Magic, Fortify Illusion, Regenerate Magic, and Restore Magicka.  When they are combined with Alchemy, does the resulting potion have all four properties (even though one is negative and the rest are positive) and if not what does this result in?

Comment: Yes, they all appear. Also, you can create a potion with three ingredients, and there are like 100 ingredients. So it would be a ginormous list.

Comment: Interesting, I assumed that with three ingredients all of them would need to share multiple effects to get a multiple effect potion, if that isn't the case this list wouldn't be a useful as I thought.

Comment: Nope. If A and B have restore health, and B and C have restore stamina, the potion will have both. If A has effects 1,2,3,4; B has effects 1,2,5,6; and C has effects 3,4,5,6; the resulting potion will have all six effects (I assume -- I've never done more than four effects, and haven't looked to see if it's possible.)

Comment: I have both dwarven oil and taproot ... need to try this sometime

Comment: `Deathbell, Impstool, Human Flesh` and `River Betty, Large Antlers, Deathbell` both create very powerful poisons!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Dwarven Oil and Taproot have the exact same effects: Weakness to Magic, Fortify Illusion, Regenerate Magic, and Restore Magicka.

If you create a potion from these ingredients, it would have all four effects (3 positive, 1 negative).  With the Purity perk, the negative effect would not appear.  As a potion, you can drink it.

If you create a poison from these ingredients, it would have all four effects (3 positive, 1 negative).  With the Purity perk, the 3 positive effects would not appear.  As a poison, you can put it on your weapon.

Comment: I assume that potion would be ... valuable

Comment: @Coomie funnily enough it would be less valuable without the negative effect. How do you choose if it's a potion or a poison?

Answer (score 9):

I've created a [potion "calculator"](http://rp.eliteskills.com/skyrim.html) which you can use to see the result of combining various ingredients.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, this spreadsheet shows all the possible combinations and you can easily filter it to show only the 4 or 5 effect potions.  Sadly, even though 6 effects would be possible, there aren't any valid potions like that.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtdL1GrYQUbldE5PUmlQT1JOYUVaUkk2TkFqMzBzSnc

Comment: Just for reference, there are 264 four effect potions, and 4 five effect potions: `Bear Claws, Eye of Sabre Cat, Hanging Moss`; `Creep Cluster, Mora Tapinella, Scaly Pholiota`; `Daedra Heart, Eye of Sabre Cat, Silverside Perch`; and `Glow Dust, Glowing Mushroom, Hanging Moss`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the alchemy section of SegmentNext's [crafting guide](http://segmentnext.com/2011/11/13/elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-crafting-guide-alchemy-smithing-and-enchantment/#alchemy) very helpful.  In addition to explaining how ingredients combine, it lists each possible effect, which ingredients provide them, and how strong they are.

Comment: One especially potent poison I discovered is Imp Stool+Briar Heart+Slaughterfish egg. I wont tell you what it does but trust me in the right hands its deadly! The same effect can be accomplished with Imp Stool+Canis Root+Mora Tapinella.