# Does the number of ingredients in a potion affect its strength?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does anyone know if there is any benefit in mixing ingredients where 3 of them share the same effect?

I created a potion that had 2 ingredients with fire resist, and then another where 3 ingredients had fire resist, and the fire resist stats were the same with both potions.

I was wondering if this is true for all effects or if maybe some effects had boosted stat if all 3 ingredients shared it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, mixing more than two ingredients with the same effect doesn't create a stronger effect.

The only thing that changes the strength of the effect is your current alchemy level + perks + enchantments.

Given this, theoretically the strongest potion or poison that can be made will have at most 6 effects.

Reference: Personal experience + I saw it on a wiki page I can no longer find.

Comment: I've noticed that certain combinations of deathbell gives a stronger damage health than other combinations, but other than that, I've seen no differences in ingredient combinations.

Comment: @yx. Certain ingredients do have stronger effects than others, but having more ingredients doesn't help; only the magnitude of the strongest one is relevant. See http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy_Effects

Comment: @Annan There aren't actually any six effect potion recipes, though it would theoretically be possible, but there are four five effect potions. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/37278/12574